# Allowing user to type html tags and save them to file to display on website

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, security

I am writing blogging software from scratch (mostly as a learning experience). My method of allowing the blog owner to make a new post is for them to type the post into a form (textarea), including formatting tags such as `<br />`, and then use PHP to create a file and write it with the contents of the text area. This file is then loaded into the main blog page via an iframe.

My question is: how can I make this reasonably secure? As at the moment the owner could type anything (so could potentially add javascript or something). The owner interface is behind a login screen, and the textarea content never gets saved to a database, just a file, so my MySQL is safe enough. Just worried that blog owners (or anyone who got past the login screen) could create dangerous files.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Have you read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php?

Comment: use mark down or bbcode and strip all html tags else you're opening your code up to a whole host of injection attacks both JS and other include related xss style attacks

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent xss but allow all html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826970/prevent-xss-but-allow-all-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) to strip tags that aren't allowed.

```
echo strip_tags('<p>Hello, I am a paragraph. <a href="#">And I am a link</a></p><script>// I am something that will be stripped</script>','<p><a>');
```

would output

```
<p>Hello, I am a paragraph. <a href="#">And I am a link</a></p>// I am something that will be stripped<p><a>
```

Comment: I'm a noob, I'm using strip_tags to clean up database input, I didn't look closely and realise I could let certain tags through if I wanted. Doh! Thank you!

Comment: @Feathers no problem :) But I wouldn't trust strip tags on cleaning database input, as it doesn't stop an sql injection. PDO and prepared statements are the solution :)

Comment: At the moment anything going into the database is being run through this:

Comment: function sanitizeString($var) {
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    return $var;
}

function sanitizeMySQL ($var) {
    $var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
    $var = sanitizeString($var);
    return $var;
}

Comment: @Feathers Looks secure to me, but why do it so hard? :) Stackoverflow has a very good and simple page for pdo & prepared statements. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info