# Ignore wrong html syntax

Tags: html

I create templates, mostly for webshops.

My template:

```
<div class="product_desc">
    [variableForDescription]
</div>
```

If my clients add products, especially the product description, sometimes they paste incorrect html code. For example a closing div-tag:

```
<div class="product_desc">
   <p>nice product</p></div>
</div>
```

sometimes the result is that the whole template is broken. I´m not able to check the description with php. Is there any way to ignore such wrong code so that the wrong code in the "product_desc"-div does not affect the rest of the template?

Answer (score 1):

HTML provides no mechanism to do that.

If you provide software to insert the submitted data into the template then you could build a check into that software (preferably one that involves a real HTML parser).

This is the same technique used to [defend against XSS while allowing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826970/prevent-xss-but-allow-all-html-tags).