# How to sanitize input and prevent XSS attack

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor, xss, sanitization

I am planning to use CKEDITOR at my asp.net application.

But i see that they don't prevent any way to prevent XSS attack at server side.

So how can i prevent XSS attack ? How can i sanitize input ?

What is the most effective sanitizer for asp.net c# ?

So i am basically looking for a decent solution to sanitize CKEDITOR input and display it back to the users safely. Thank you.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
  <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:TextBox ID="ckEditor" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('ckEditor');
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060923/sanitize-html-before-storing-in-the-db-or-before-rendering-antixss-library-in

Comment: @christiandev so do you know any way to safely encode and decode CKEDITOR input data ?